# Tracking Acquisition for Directed Scan

Tags: tracking

My problem: create a device that can take a scan of a target via a camera and a shooting rig (that I am building).

The camera is connected to a motor that **rotates** the camera, and this is connected to a belt that **translates** left/right on a rail.

Diagram: [image: http://imgur.com/Eq3Sn]

I leave the translation motor's speed alone and let it go fully from start to finish without giving it any other commands. However for the rotation motor I compare the desired position with the actual position and give it an error value via an error function (negative means its too slow and positive means its too fast). Depending on the magnitude of the error value I either speed up or slow down the rotation motor.

However I am not getting much success as the tracking of the target is quite inaccurate. And I made up the error function - I have been trying to tweak it using trial and error but it isn't providing satisfying results.

Anybody have tips on how to solve this either than tweaking my error function? Is there any resources (books, internet guideS) for such a Tracking Acquisition project?

Comment: What are you using as your error function? What is your goal? Are you trying to keep the target at boresight of your camera at all times? There will likely be some tricks to getting such a tracking system to work due to the different coordinate systems used by the two motors; motion that is linear in one system is nonlinear in the other.

Comment: The error functions Yes that's my goal, with a little bit of slack. The error function is parabolic if it should speed up and cubic if it needs to slow down. The function is all made-up though from testing.